# Superior DNS Management Options?

Tags: dns, hosting, subdomain

I have quite a few domains that I manage (100+) and I'm getting tired of GoDaddy's management.  Whenever I need to make changes shifting things around to DreamHost or Heroku to Google App Engine or my own VPS and private servers things eventually get hairy and it's tiresome to have to go to multiple locations in order to manage things.

I was curious if there was a solid option for developers that need robust domain management.  I don't really (and PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong) see an answer with DynDNS or EasyDNS options.  Perhaps I'm overlooking something.

I'm really looking for a single console to rule them all (i.e., register wherever and set NS entries to the master service) and to then be able to go into a domain and, by using a template split everything out to where I want it go go.  In other words by setting up my own DNS templates I could with one fell swoop set up Google Apps sub domains, development dyndns cnames, AWS CDNs, etc. etc. etc.

Anyone aware of such a comprehensive solution?

Comment: I also use GoDaddy's and have the same opinion. If you find a good alternative, please let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite happy with DynDNS but I'm equally satisfied with [Zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com/). Templates, AJAX interface, migration tools, an [API](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns/rest-api)...

Short of deploying your own infrastructure or piggybacking off something like [Dynect](http://dyn.com/dns/dynect-managed-dns/), I'd hazard that Zerigo should do everything you want. The fact that it's recently been acquired by 8x8 suggests other people agree.

[I don't work for them if this sounds like a plug ;)]